# hyperledger fabric devmode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to deploy chaincode in devmod on my ubuntu machine. I am following this tutorial.

The issue is when I use this command : `CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGLEVEL=debug CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=localhost:7052 npm start`

it shows the following error:

```
2018-09-20T16:27:18.292Z ERROR [lib/handler.js] uncaughtException: The "peer.address" program argument must be set to a legitimate value of <host>:<port>
```

Full logs can be found here:
https://hastebin.com/arerozesad.sql

I am following this tutorial:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.6/peer-chaincode-devmode.html

Comment: how about directly using `CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1:7052`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I hope you are using Fabric v1.1 or later as Node.js chaincode is not supported in v1.0.x.

The instructions you listed are for running Go chaincode.
For Node.js chaincode, your command should look like

`CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME="mycc:v0" node mycc.js --peer.address grpc://localhost:7052`

You should be able to replace `node mycc.js` with `npm start` as well.

See https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-node#test-nodejs-chaincode for more information.